# How to check if a cell value is an error or is < 0?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I've tried to use the or statement inside an if statement but I´ve got "type mismatch" error. Both `Cell.value < 0` and `WorksheetFunction.IsError(Cell.Value)` return true or false, correct? So, what´s the type mismatch?

Thanks!

```
For Each Cell In RatioThU
     If Cell.Value < 0 Or WorksheetFunction.IsError(Cell.Value) Then '<--TYPE MISMATCH!
        Cell.EntireRow.Select
           Selection.Font.StrikeThrough = True
     End If
Next
```

Comment: Excel will evaluate both terms before combining them with the Or.  If the cell value is in error `Cell.Value < 0` will return type mismatch.  You need `If Error Then` `Strikeout row` `Else` `If Cell.Value < 0 Then` `Strikeout row` `End If` `End If`

Comment: Tony, your explanation was perfect. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must separate the tests:

```
For Each cell In RatioThU
     If WorksheetFunction.IsError(cell) Then
        cell.EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
    Else
        If cell.Value < 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
        End If
     End If
Next
```

Notice **Selection** is not necessary.

Comment: Of course, I didn't eve pay attention to that part. The Selection will cause performance issues in larger loops.

Answer (score 3):

An error value in a cell in the selected range is causing the type mismatch on the Cell.Value = 0 check.

Check first for the error condition, then for the cell value like so...

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsError(Cell.Value) = "True" Then
     Cell.EntireRow.Select
         Selection.Font.Strikethrough = True
ElseIf Cell.Value = 0 Then   
    Cell.EntireRow.Select
       Selection.Font.Strikethrough = True
End If
```

Do you know how to step through code and add a watch? It is very useful for debugging errors like this and something well worth investigating.

Comment: In this situation, step through the code was not useful because one of the two arguments used in the if statement (< 0 and isError) was causing the problem. But thanks for the tip, it´s really useful!

Comment: Your answer and Gary's are very similar, but I've chosen Gary's because the code use < 0 and not = 0. But thanks!!

Comment: I must have changed that while debugging. Gary's Student answered first and made further improvements to the code. I agree with the marking as answer :)